# Parsing Lucene Query syntax and escaping for CloudSearch

Tags: c#, regex, lucene, lucene.net, amazon-cloudsearch

Basically, I have an application that needs to support both Lucene.NET and Amazon CloudSearch.

So, I can't re-write the queries, I need to use the standard queries from lucene, and use the .ToString() on the query to get the syntax.

The issue is that in Lucene.NET (I don't know if this is the same in the java version), the .ToString() method return the raw string without the escape characters.

Therefore, things like:

```
(title:blah:blah summary:"lala:la")
```

should be

```
(title:blah\:blah summary:"lala\:la")
```

What I need is a regex that will add the escapes.

Is this possible? and if so, what would it look like.

Some additional possible variances:

```
(title:"this is a search:term")
(field5:"this is a title:term")
```

Comment: You'd probably do `Regex.Replace(query, ([-+!(){}[\]^"~*?:]|(?:\|\|)|(?:&&)), "\\$1");`

Comment: What are exact requirements? Where and what should be escaped? Just `:`? When it is second colon in a non-whitespace sequence? Try [`(?<=\S+?:\S+?):`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5cS%2b%3f%3a%5cS%2b%3f)%3a&i=(title%3a%22this+is+a+search%3aterm%22)%0d%0a(title%3ablah%5c%3ablah+summary%3a%22lala%5c%3ala%22)%0d%0a&r=%5c%22).

Comment: You are more encoding then parsing.  .NET has several encoders.  Not the one you need but look around  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on comments and edits, it seems that you want any query string to be able to be correctly escaped by the regex, and any given lucene query to be accurately represented by the resulting string.

*That ain't gonna happen.*

Lucene query syntax is not capable of expressing all lucene queries.  In fact, the string you get from `Query.toString()` often can't even be *parsed* by the `QueryParser`, nevermind being an accurate reconstruction of the query.

The long and short of it:  You are going about this the wrong way.  `Query.ToString()` is *not* designed to serialize the query, and it's goal is *not* to create a parsable string query.  It's mainly for debugging and such.  If you keep attempting to use it this way, this tomfoolery of trying to use a regex to escape ambiguous query syntax will likely just be the *start* of your troubles.

[This question provides another example of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966287/lucene-4-2-stringfield).

Comment: It would be so cool is there was a query parser for all (at least more) syntax

Comment: well, that.... sucks...  It looks like, for "simple" queries, I can get pretty far by replicating the logic of .ToString() method (gotta love open source).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to escape the colon `:` at strategic points of the string

```
(?<!title|summary):
```

Then escape the captured colon `:`

**Explanation**

Look behind `?<!` for any colon that is not followed by `title` or `summary`, then match the colon `:`

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xX8nG4/5)

**input**

```
(title:blah:blah summary:"lala:la")
```

**Output**

```
(title:blah\:blah summary:"lala\:la")
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, however, I should have been clear that title and summary are only 2 of hundreds of fields, some of which I don't know the name of at compile time.

Comment: Also, if the text contained `title:"something title:go"` that wouldn't be captured properly would it?

Comment: i answered based on your question. Depending on how complex the string is, you can always modify the pattern. For your question, this pattern would work `(?<!title:"|summary):(?!")` see demo https://regex101.com/r/xX8nG4/6